# Is it possible to a apply count function on a folder and then delete a file when folder exceed a limit?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script which can delete an old file from a directory when a directory exceeds a certain limit.
Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
#incremental backup of upload folder only
LIMIT=2
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y%s`
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tgz
SRCDIR=/home/Man/blabla
DESDIR=/home/Man/newdir
EXCFILE=/home/Man/blabla/up
if [ $LIMIT -gt 2 ]; then 
cd $DESDIR
ls -lt | grep .tgz | tail -n 1 | xargs -r rm
tar -cvzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR --exclude=$EXCFILE 
else
tar -cvzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR --exclude=$EXCFILE 
fi
```

But it is not working it creates backup but not deleting the old file after the dir exceeds the limit

Comment: A limit of what?

Comment: add limit to destination folder. As destination folder contain backup tar i want that the destination folder only contains 2 files whenever a new file added it delete the old one.

Comment: That's logrotate's job.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot (it is unclear). Explain what *limit* do you care about. Explain what and where are the big files you want to get rid of. Motivate your question (e.g. why don't you use backup programs or  `logrotate`?)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear (we can just guess what "limit" means, but we don't understand what it is), and lacks motivation.

At the [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) level (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)), the relevant system calls are [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_FSIZE` then [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) related ones (e.g. [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)) with `SIGXFSZ`.

So you might use the `ulimit` builtin and the `trap` one. However, a program executed by your shell script might change the file size limit, and could catch the `SIGXFSZ` signal.

Beware, the size of a directory (as given by [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), so [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) & [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)) is *not* the accumulated size of its files (since some files could be [hard-linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) in *several* directories; files are [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) - see [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)). It is just the size of directory entries.

Alternatively, you might compute the accumulated size of files (using [du(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) or [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) or [gawk(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html)) and take some action according to it, maybe deleting some big files (But consider -perhaps by deciding to ignore them- *other processes* writing files or directories during the execution of your script).

Perhaps you could be interested by [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) (see [quotactl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/quotactl.2.html), [quota(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/quota.1.html), [quotacheck(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/quotacheck.8.html))

You could do [incremental backups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup). You might use other utilities than [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) for that purpose (e.g. [dar](http://dar.linux.free.fr/), [afio](https://linux.die.net/man/1/afio), ...). Notice that [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) & [cp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) & [tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/backup.html#SEC90) have some `--backup` option. Perhaps you might consider [logrotate(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html) to deal with growing log files.

Answer (score 0):

Why i didn't used logrotate because that was not the requirement. Anyways I have solved it by myself. I add a count funtion which counts the .tgz files in a directory and whenever $count exceeds $limit the old file will get remove.

```
LIMIT=3 
COUNT=$(ls $DESDIR | grep '\.tgz$' | wc -l )
if [ "$COUNT" -gt "$LIMIT" ]; then
cd $DESDIR
ls -t | grep .tgz | tail -n "+$(($LIMIT + 1))" | xargs -r rm && tar -cvzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR --exclude=$EXCFILE --exclude=$EXCSNRFILE
else 
echo "script is not working"
```